# Integral of Bessel function of a square root

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

Any idea how to calculate the following integral?
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} K_1\left(\sqrt{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\theta}\right)d\theta
$$
This integral appears when using perturbation theory for the electron-electron interaction in cylindrical coordinates, and should have been addressed by someone in the literature, but somehow I cannot manage to find anything related. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Leafing through Gradshteyn & Rizhik, I found 6.684:
$$
\int_0^\pi (\sin x)^{2\nu}
\frac{J_\nu\big(\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2-2\alpha\beta\cos x}\;\big)}
{\big(\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2-2\alpha\beta\cos x}\;\big)^\nu} \;dx
= 2^\nu\sqrt{\pi}\;\Gamma\left(\nu+\frac{1}{2}\right)
\frac{J_\nu(\alpha)}{\alpha^\nu}\;\frac{J_\nu(\beta)}{\beta^\nu}
$$
and something similar with $Y_\nu$.

But that doesn't seem to help with yours.